# Is there a syntax theme in atom-editor similar to jsbin midnight?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am looking for a atom-editor syntax theme similar to jsbin midnight theme but having a tough time finding one. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!!!

[image]